# How can I filter different key words from one collection into another one?and put them together.

Tags: mongodb

I used the aggregate, match and out query, however, if I want to filter C and also put into B collection, there will be a problem that A will disapper, only left C.

So do you have any query that I can filter from "location" collection and put my keywords.A,c and others all into B collection?

It sees $out only can have one keyword

Comment: Would you care to show your attempts so far?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I think I asked in a bad way. I think the item is unique in the database. I  can not put different data in same collection.